# Excel extracting text into columns

Tags: excel, vba, text, split, substring

Is there a way to extract data from a single cell and split it into columns by headers. For example we have in A1 cell text like this:

```
Name: John
Address: USA, New York
Age: 66
```

I want to split this text into columns with headers `Name`, `Address`, `Age` and extract data to the following columns. I'd be grateful for tips.

Comment: Which version of excel do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is little bit tricky but will work on all version of excel. As per below screenshot Put `Name`, `Address`, `Age` to `B1`,`C1` & `D1` cell then put below formula to `B2` cell then drag down and right as needed.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",100)),((COLUMN(A$2)-1)*100)+1,COLUMN($A$2)*100)),B1&": ","")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice idea + to stretch original strings and rejust them afterwards. Nevertheless rows 2 and following seem to *include* the prefixed strings "Name: ", "Address: " and "Age: " instead of substituting them with "". - FYI added a VBA array approach via filtering.

Answer (score 2):

If you wouldn't mind using formulas instead of VBA:

---

With Excel O365:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(TRIM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,":",CHAR(10)),CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 0]")))
```

With Excel 2013 or higher, other than O365:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A2,":",CHAR(10)),CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 0]")),COLUMN(A1))
```

And drag over and down...

Comment: Any other way of doing this in Excel / Power Pivot/ Power BI? Unfortunately I don't have access to ver 0365.

Comment: @WojciechUrjasz, for sure. Though I added an non O365 version of the `FILTERXML` route.

Comment: Worth mentioning that JvDV posted an excellent overview of `FilterXML` XPath cases at [Extract substrings using FilterXML()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml/61837697#61837697). FYI posted an alternative VBA approach. @JvdV

Answer (score 2):

**A VBA array approach**

This late post in addition to the valid answers above demonstrates an array approach and a double splitting:

- section **`[1]`** splits into lines via the `vbLf` delimiter (equalling `Chr(10)`),
- section **`[2]`** restricts splitting to two parts (via ": ")

As it's not so widely known how to use the `Split()` function by *limiting* output to 2 tokens only as shown in section `[2]`, have a look at the

**Syntax**

> Split(expression, [ delimiter, [ **limit**, [ compare ]]])

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitIntoTokens()
With Sheet1                                   ' << change to your project's sheet Code(Name)
    '[0] get string content
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim data As Variant
    data = .Range("A1:D" & lastRow).Value
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To UBound(data)
        '[1] split into lines
        '    ~> Name: John|Address: USA, New York|Age: 66
        Dim lines: lines = Split(data(i, 1), vbLf)
        
        '[2] split into 2 parts only and take the 2nd one
        Dim ii As Long, tmp
        For ii = 0 To UBound(lines)
            lines(ii) = Split(lines(ii), ": ", 2)(1)    ' split via ": "-delimiter, 2nd part via index (1)
            data(i, ii + 2) = lines(ii)
        Next
        'Debug.Print Join(lines, "|") optional (display results in VB Editors Immediate Window
    Next
    
    '[3] write array results back to sheet
    .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(data), 4) = data             ' write data
    .Range("A1:D1") = Split("Data,Name,Address,Age", ",")   ' write header (if not existant)
End With
End Sub
```